# Data in text is not proper format after converting PDF to text

Tags: pdfbox

I have 1 PDF file. I need to fetch key values.
I am able to convert PDF to text by using pdfBox and itext api's but text is not in proper format. I need to get the values from the text and have to do some calculation.
Below is the piece of code:

```
PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();  
stripper.setSortByPosition(true);  
PDFTextStripper pstripper = new PDFTextStripper();  
String text = pstripper.getText(pddoc);  
String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n");  
for (String line : lines) {  
System.out.println(line);  
}  
pddoc.close();
```

Could you please help me on this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please share your PDF file and explain what you expected, and what you got instead. Also try the sort option of the stripper.